# Laravel 5.x How do you create a new user that has a foreign key constraint?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm able to create a new user by using:

```
User::create([
    'username' => $data[ 'username' ],
    'email' => $data[ 'email' ],
    'first_name' => $data[ 'first_name' ],
    'last_name' => $data[ 'last_name' ],
    'password' => bcrypt($data[ 'password' ]),
]);
```

But now I want to create a user that now has a constraint of region_id, so I thought it would be accomplished by adding region_id to fillable, and adding it to user create:

```
User::create([
    'region_id' => $data[ 'region_id'
    'username' => $data[ 'username' ],
    'email' => $data[ 'email' ],
    'first_name' => $data[ 'first_name' ],
    'last_name' => $data[ 'last_name' ],
    'password' => bcrypt($data[ 'password' ]),
]);
```

In my migration I added:

```
$table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('region_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('regions');
```

and seeded it using a factory by just assigning the region_id, but registration fails now in the application and throws:

```
Undefined index: region_id
```

I looked at the docs again and saw that I can add an index to the migration on this field, but after a bit more reading it seems like MySQL might actually automatically index foreign keys.

Comment: Are you sure your `$data` array actually has a value stored under `$data[ 'region_id']`?

Comment: Hi @Mastergalen, yep that was it.  In Angular I had set the select directive using ngOptions, but was passing the options region object back and not region.id for region.name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify that `$data` array contains `region_id`
2. Do not add `region_id` in fillable fields, Rather do this:

   ```
   $region = Region::find($data['region_id']);

   $region->users()->create([
      'username' => $data['username'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
      'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
      'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
   ]);
   ```

   This will authomatically add `region_id` field in user object.

> Note: Make sure you have region hasMany users relationship in region model.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  What do you do if you need to add two foreign key values to users, for example: a user has a region_id, but also a rental_id, and a vehicle_id?  I have all the relationships setup just not sure how you're supposed to set them using the ORM.